# Getting really frustrated with ActionScript 3, I can't get an extremely basic switch program to work

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm really new to programming, and am in a grade 11 programming class. I have finished every basic assignment in less than 5 minutes so far, but for this I'm getting really fed up.

```
input.border=true;
input.restrict="0-9.";

var cat:int;

Enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(event:MouseEvent) {
    cat=int(input);
    switch(cat) { 
    case 1: 
        output.text="74-95 mph or 64-82 kt or 119-153 km/hr";
        break; 
    case 2: 
        output.text="96-110 mph or 83-95 kt or 154-177 km/hr"; 
        break; 
    case 3: 
        output.text="111-130 mph or 96-113 kt or 178-209 km/hr"; 
        break; 
    case 4: 
        output.text="131-155 mph or 114-135 kt or 210-249 km/hr"; 
        break; 
    case 5: 
        output.text="greater than 155 mph or 135 kt or 249 km/hr"; 
        break; 
    default:
        output.text="Out of Range!"
        break;
    }
}
```

The output should change depending on what the input is (0-9) but it just always says out of range no matter what. This makes ABSOLUTELY 0 sense to me. Any help?

Comment: which line throws "out of range"?

Comment: Also, your "default" output line is missing a semi-colon at the end.

Comment: try:   cat = int( input.text );

Comment: Since you are still learning here's an advice for you: trace. In all programming language there's a way to trace values and it's no coincidence, all programmers no matter how good they are need at some point to check values just to make sure everything works as intended. If you had done this very simple thing: trace(cat) you would have fixed the problem in about 30 seconds top.

Comment: Just to be clear my comment is in no way sarcastic or condescendent. It's really just an advice and it's a good one that does save a lot of time for a lot of coders. There was no need to be so aggressive about it.

Answer (score 1):

> cat=int(input);

You are assigning the variable `cat` to the int version of a `flash.text.TextField` object, that would evaluated to 0 (thanks @akmozo).

Try assigning it to the `text` property of the TextField as that contains your input value:

```
cat=int(input.text);
trace(cat);
```

[`flash.text.TextField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#text)

> **text property**
> text:String
>
> A string that is the current text in the text field.